# Random redirect to /Undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, redirect

I'm working on an internal MVC site.

**Issue:**

Suddenly the site has started redirecting to `localhost/undefined` in select browsers (Chrome, Opera, and Safari) before/after a delete POST. This does not happen in Firefox or IE.

**Steps Taken:**

I've stepped through the following javascript code numerous times on Chrome(not working) and IE(working). There appear to be no difference other than Chrome finishing with a random redirect that is not called upon in the code.

**Jquery AJAX Call below:**

```
// Delete button clicked
function deleteEntity(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var index = $(".deleteEntity[name=" + name + "]").index($(this));
    var entityId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.model.peek()[index].ID);
    var data = { EntityID: entityId };

    viewModel.model.remove(viewModel.model.peek()[index]);

    if (entityId > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/" + name + "/Delete",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Decide later.
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).on("click", ".deleteEntity", deleteEntity);
```

**Debugging Steps**:

Starting at a break at the line of the ajax call. -> `if (entityId > 0) {`.

- If I hit F8 here to pass through to my breaks at the `success` and `error` functions, it ends up not hitting either of the breakpoints and redirecting to `localhost/undefined` without contacting the server.
- If I hit F10 to step through it will stop at my breakpoint on the server in the delete action. From there I hit F5 in visual studio and it deletes the selected expected entity returning me to my breakpoint in the broswer. If I hit F8 from here it will hit success and popup the alert box with success.
- If I hit F8 in the broswer before hitting F5 in visual studio however it will instantly redirect to `localhost/undefined`.

**Question:** Does anyone know the origin of this problem? I've googled around and found a very similar issue relating to plugins so I tried disabling all of the (a whole 2) and it did not change anything.

p.s. if any other code snippets will be helpful just comment and I'll add them. I've checked my actions over at least 20 times. The `Delete` is an `[HttpPost]` but so is my `Update` and it's working fine in the same exact fashion.

Comment: You should answer the question yourself, and then make a new question for any additional problems you have. That way it is easier for people to be helped by similar problems.

Comment: Alright I'll do that. I figured since it was so closely related I'd just edit the question, but that works too I suppose.

Comment: True, though people search by title many times :)

Comment: @Shelby115 Don't edit your question to include new questions.  If you have a new question, then use the Ask Question button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the `[HttpPost]` attribute from my Delete action in my controller. (I had to add the Json return to allow get but that was just because it was no longer a post request).

I am clue-less as to why it was causing such an error and will be asking a separate question in regards to that. If an answer is found I will link it here in this post.