# Why HttpPost was causing a /undefine redirect in some browsers

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

**Backstory:**

I recently had a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068259/random-redirect-to-undefined) where when I clicked my delete button on my MVC page to delete a record it would remove the record but instantly redirect to `localhost/undefined` at no call to any redirects. I was using a JQuery AJAX call on button click to post with the delete action returning a `Json(new { Success = true });`. This worked perfectly in FireFox and IE (both 32bit and 64bit versions), however; it caused the redirect to `localhost/undefined` in Chrome, Opera, and Safari browsers.

I solved this problem by removing the `[HttpPost]` attribute on my delete action on my controller.

**Code: (HTML/Razor)**

```
<button name="Estimate" type="submit" class="deleteEntity" tabindex="-1" data-bind="attr: { href: '/Estimate/Select?EntityID=' + ko.utils.unwrapObservable($data.ID) }" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;background-color: #FFFFFF;border-color: #FFFFFF;margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <img src="/Content/Images/red-x.png" />
</button>
```

**Code: (AJAX)**

```
// Delete button clicked
function deleteEntity(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var index = $(".deleteEntity[name=" + name + "]").index($(this));
    var entityId = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel.model.peek()[index].ID);
    var data = { EntityID: entityId };

    viewModel.model.remove(viewModel.model.peek()[index]);

    if (entityId > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/" + name + "/Delete",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Decide later.
            }
        });
    }
}

$(document).on("click", ".deleteEntity", deleteEntity);
```

**Code: Action (Before fixing the problem)**

```
/// <summary>
/// POST: Deletes the specified entity from the database.
/// </summary>
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Int32? EntityID )
{
    // Delete the estimate given its ID.
    if ((EntityID ?? 0) > 0)
    {
        Db.DeleteEntity(EntityID ?? 0);

        if (EntityID == this.ActiveSelection.EstimateID)
        {
            this.ActiveSelection = null;
        }
    }

    return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

**Question(s):**

- Why was I getting a random redirect to `localhost/undefined` (in select browsers) from it solely being (what I assume as) mislabeled (i.e. `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpGet]`)?
- Shouldn't it be an `[HttpPost]` request? Would delete not be a Post? I'm guessing that I was doing something wrong on this? Might someone have an explanation?
- If so, Was I simply just performing the `HttpPost` wrong? How would I go about doing the `HttpPost` so that it doesn't cause the random redirect?

I have my suspicions of where I went wrong, but am not certain for sure and still don't fully understand why it caused the error or what about that part was wrong.

**Network Tab Header for Delete:**

This is while stopped on a breakpoint at the AJAX Success function `alert(data);`.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:59635
Request URL:http://localhost:59635/Estimate/Delete
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=xwxxnwy3ke2zvtztnnsngz3a
Host:localhost:59635
Origin:http://localhost:59635
Referer:http://localhost:59635/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
EntityID:25
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:16
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 09 Jun 2014 17:53:37 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:4.0
```

Comment: Can you show the headers of the page that was making a redirect? It may help a lot.

Comment: Try doing console.log() after each variables, and see what gets dumped and you might solve your issue faster

Comment: Yes, you should be using POST. Examine the network request/response headers to give you more clues.

Comment: Could using `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;` at the end of my `deleteEntity` function cause it? A co-worker brought this point up. I'll put the code back to the way it was and check the headers as well as see if my coworker's concern is correct.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default browser behavior. If you use that within a form submission handler, the form will not be submitted by the browser but instead with the javascript (usually AJAX) that you provide instead.

Comment: My coworker's concern was inaccurate, he thought it might be skipping over the `e.preventDefault()` somehow but adding `return false;` did not solve the previous issue. I added the network headers.

Comment: It looks like this request is succeeding -- Content-Length:16 corresponds to `{"Success":true}`. If you use the _preserve log_ option with the network monitor, do you see an additional request after this POST-delete?

Comment: @Jasen yes, it's deciding to do a request labeled: 'undefined' which is a GET that returns a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55337/discussion-between-jasen-and-shelby115).

Answer (score 0):

ugh. I had this little baby I forgot about....

```
/* Entity Selection */ 
function onImageClick(e) { 
var image = $(this); 
var link = $(image).attr("href"); 

window.location.href = link; 
} 

// Enabled onClick events. 
$(document).on("click", "tbody tr td img", onImageClick); // Solved the problem by adding ".selectEntity" to the selector.
```

I think it kind of explains itself why I was having issues. *cough cough*. Sorry about that. Thank you for all that commented trying to help.